# AfterItemExpand extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using extjs *4.0.7* and I need to use the event **afterItemExpand** in a tree panel, but it exist since the *4.1.0* version.
Does anybody know what event can I use or what can I overwrite in the extjs code?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you could copy the code from the extjs4.1 code (event declaration and event fire)

Comment: You'd need to override the `onExpand` method in `Ext.tree.View`. If it's not animating, fire the event before it returns early. Otherwise, fire the event in the animate callback.

Comment: Are you using Menu tree like parent / child structure? And on parent item expand , you want to do something?